# Can I use only HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

## Context

I've an object O with 4 primitive variables:

- a, b, c and d. (All 4 mandatory)
- The first 3 are keys, I used them to generate hashcode and equals.
- "d" is a counter, it begin from 1.
- I've an HashSet and a loop that insert O items,
- if HashSet contains a duplicate (key: a,b,c), I would modify the item O stored in HashSet to do d++ (otherwise I add the item to HashSet).

But I can't get item from HashSet (HashSet doesn't have the .get method).

## Question

So the only (and best) way to handle this is to make HashMap ?

## My solution

```
    class O {
       int a, b, c, d;

       boolean equals(Object o) { /* handle only a,b,c */ }
       int hashCode() { /* handle only a,b,c */ }
    }

...


        HashMap<O, O> group = new HashMap<O, O>();
        O curr = null;
...
            while (...) //Iterate the result set from a query where I can't use groupBy
            {
                curr = new O();
                curr.setA(...);
                curr.setB(...);
                curr.setC(...);
                O ex = group.get(curr);
                if (ex != null)
                {
                    ex.setD(ex.getD()+1);
                }
                else
                {
                    group.put(curr , curr);
                }
            }
```

Comment: no, through HashSet it is possible

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: I think HashMap suits well, why not use it?

Comment: It is not clear, why you can't get item from HashSet.

Comment: just to recap, and whether I have understood the issue correctly. You want the HashMap with private get method?

Comment: @t-benze just want to know if it's possible to use HashSet. 
guillaumegirod HashSet doesn't have the .get method.

Comment: @Accollativo through HashSet it is possible

Comment: @Accollativo Certainly you can do an iteration over the set and look for a match, it has the same effect, just not as efficient as the get() of HashMap.

Comment: @vishalgajera How? HashSet doesn't have .get. 


if (list.contains(o) { O o2= list.get(o); o2.getD++; }

Comment: @Accollativo you are right, Map is best approach, but just i am saying through HashSet  also it is possible. but while req. like accesing is complicated. so Map is best.

Answer (score 2):

I think an easier method might be to have the following:

```
class O {
   int a, b, c;

   boolean equals(Object o) { /* your code */ }
   int hashCode() { /* your code */ }
}

Map<O, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (O obj: oCollection) {
   if (map.contains(obj)) {
       map.put(obj, map.get(obj) + 1);
   } else {
       map.put(obj, 1);
   }
}
```

This way you can just count them using the `HashMap` rather than the extra field in the class.

Comment: yes, this was nearly my solution. Just class O have 4 variable int a, b, c, d;

Comment: Yes, but I'm saying you don't need `d`, you can use the HashMap to do the counting instead. If you want you can still have `d` but it is not needed anymore with the Map construction.

Comment: Yes I don't need d for this task, but it's a prerequisite for other stuff, so the object must be in that way.

Comment: Sure you can still include it. Just don't use it in the hashcode method

Answer (score 1):

Short answers: Yes, you can use a HashSet, looking for an element using iterators, but that solution is cumbersome. The HashMap approach is far better in terms of readability and performance. Is it the best option? As always, it depends...

As you are not defining limits to the libraries you can use, let me introduce you the interface [Bag, from the Apache collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/Bag.html):

> Defines a collection that counts the number of times an object appears
>   in the collection. Suppose you have a Bag that contains {a, a, b, c}.
>   Calling getCount(Object) on a would return 2, while calling
>   uniqueSet() would return {a, b, c}.